# SwiftUI – How can I change a @State property with a list item tap?

Tags: swiftui

Within my List I have some static items. I want to dynamically hide/show an item when the user taps another list item, i.e. I want to change a @State property when the user taps a specific list item.

How do I do that?

```
struct EditTransactionView : View {
    @State var date = Date()
    @State private var showingDateSelector = false // How do I change this with a tap on the date list item?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                DateView(date: $date)
                if showingDateSelector {
                    DatePicker(
                        $date,
                        maximumDate: Date(),
                        displayedComponents: .date )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this :

```swift
struct EditTransactionView : View {
    @State var date = Date()
    @State private var showingDateSelector = false // How do I change this with a tap on the date list item?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Button(action: { self.showingDateSelector.toggle() }) {
                    DateView(date: $date)
                }
                if showingDateSelector {
                    DatePicker(
                        $date,
                        maximumDate: Date(),
                        displayedComponents: .date )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```